# About Android Query library

Tags: android

Firstly thank you for your work, I always find answers here

My name is Miguel, i´m 17 years old and I'm learning programming 
android .. and English :)

This question is about android library Query (Aquery)
http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

I have two days reading the documentation of the library, discussion 
groups and examples.

I am primarily interested loading pictures but my problem, after two 
days of reading, I have not even managed to run the simple example.

...aq.id (R.id.image1). image ("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/ 
vikispot/android-w.png");

I understand where it says "aq" is the object AQuery and understand 
the concepts, but can not get it to work. I'm not sure where related 
to the ImageView of my Layout and other things.

My request is this, I'm sure if I had the complete sample (activity 
and xml) as loading a simple image of a url in a imageview could 
understand I'm doing wrong so I can continue with all other examples.

I appreciate the help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Best regards

Comment: What is your log cat says? What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it does absolutely nothing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest file? You must put this outside the `<application>` tag in order to use internet within your app

Comment: Yes,I´m using the internet permission. One problem is that it does not seem to connect to the Internet, so do not know if I am correctly using the library. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First add in the activity before everything,

```
private AQuery aq;
```

Second add this in the onCreate method or something.

```
aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext);
```

Also in the manifest you'll need the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```